# Cassandra: specify an initial token manually or wait for an existing bootstrap operation to finish

Tags: cassandra, bootstrapping

Am trying to bring up a small cassandra cluster with 3 nodes in it. The cluster will have one seed node. The seed node is bought up first. Once its up, I bring up both the other two nodes "AT THE SAME TIME". What I see is only one node gets added to the cluster. I get the following exception on the other node.

```
ERROR [main] 2013-03-20 11:44:57,146 CassandraDaemon.java (line 387) Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Every node is a bootstrap source! **Please specify an initial token manually or wait for an existing bootstrap operation to finish.**
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBootstrapSource(BootStrapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBalancedToken(BootStrapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBootstrapTokens(BootStrapper.java:115)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:620)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:508)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:406)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:282)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:370)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:413)
```

Does cassandra (the seed node) have a problem in handling simultaneous bootstrapping from multiple nodes? Is that a limitation? If so, any way of getting over it?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?  If 1.2 what have you set num_tokens to?

Comment: Cassandra version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you specify initial token values in each node? If not set their values, you can refer this [Cassandra Visual Ring](http://psanford.github.com/cassandra-visual-ring/)

Comment: initial_token and num_token is set blank and I want cassandra to do the bisecting. Am trying to bring up an "n" node cassandra cluster and n can vary from 3 to 50. I want cassandra to manage the token handling and hence have set initial_token and num_token to blank. The version of cassandra that I am using is 1.2.1

Comment: i am not that much aware of 1.2 series, still asking you, are you sure cassandra will manage the bisecting? becoz in 1.2 docs still i see old methods available http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/initialize/token_generation

Comment: Yes, am sure the automatic token assignment works in 1.2.1. Infact, I have some update for my problem after some tests. As was initially hypothesized - cassandra seed nodes does seem to have a problem when handling simultaneous bootstrapping. By ensuring that no two bootstraps hit the seed node at the same time, I was able to get the cluster up and running. Would be great if some cassandra developers would acknowledge that this is a known problem.